# Dozer - mapping based on condition

Tags: java, xml, dozer

Hi i am creating dozer bean mapping xml to convert from one object to another object.Now i need to map these bean based on condition. 
For example:

```
if(A == "Static")
  <field>
        <a>A</a>
        <b>T</b>
    </field>
else if (A == "Dynamic")
   <field>
        <a>A</a>
        <b>D</b>
    </field>
```

Does dozer support this kind of conditional mapping ? Kindly let me know what is the best way to achieve this ?
Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Hi @R.S Please consider accepting the answer. It tells other readers that it is correct, and gives both of us reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

No, Dozer cannot map based on such a condition. In fact this was precisely the reason why my company developed its own version of Dozer, to be able to apply more conditional cases.

I think what you're looking for is the [CustomConverter](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html) feature of Dozer, which allows you to specify the condition with a Java class. Implement the CustomConverter class, and give the full path of the Java class in the xml.

Comment: Thanks Ray..let me check.

Answer (score 0):

There is also ModelMapper that implements a conditional mapping. Have a look [here](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/property-mapping/#conditional-mapping).